# Having drop down colored backgrounds persist once selected

Tags: html

```html
<select>
    <option value="apple" style="background: red">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana" style="background: yellow">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear" style="background: green">Pear</option>
</select>
```

So I have an HTML drop down with options that have background colors. However, once I select one of these options from the list, the background color goes away...

Is there a way to make it so once an option is selected, the background color persists?

Comment: You want the background color to stay after selecting an option ?

Comment: Correct. The background reverts to the default (white?) when I select it

Answer (score 3):

i have create a  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LD8Dx/74/)

Following is the code:

```css
.Red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.Green {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.Blue {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<select name="select" class="Red" onchange="this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
     <option class="Red" value="1">Red</option>
     <option class="Green" value="2">Green</option>
     <option class="Blue" value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select style="background:pink">
    <option value="apple" style="background: red">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana" style="background: yellow">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear" style="background: green">Pear</option>
</select>
```

The selected item is a whole other object in the DOM, other style is applied to it.
You can use JavaScript or JQuery to get the color of the selected option and than apply it on the selected item.